# using python's subprocess in a cli function breaks the comamnd line

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I have written a python script to batch process video files, and I have created a CLI binding for it. You can find the repository [here](https://github.com/TheChymera/repositorg).

As part of the script (since video processing is computationally intensive) I am [using Python's subprocess module to achieve some parallelization](https://github.com/TheChymera/repositorg/blob/master/repositorg/processing.py#L54).

I am calling my script from the command line as:

```
repositorg vidproc -p "-crf 16 -c:a copy -filter:v 'crop=1080:1080:420:0'" nd750_a00{80..86}.MOV
```

and it works fine. However, after it is executed, it breaks my terminal. I can no longer see what I am typing, but it still gets sent to the terminal. This is an example of me killing the current line a few times, and then typing `ls` and hitting enter:

```
chymera@zenbookhost ~/data/cameras/nd750/a $ ^C
chymera@zenbookhost ~/data/cameras/nd750/a $ ^C
chymera@zenbookhost ~/data/cameras/nd750/a $ ^C
chymera@zenbookhost ~/data/cameras/nd750/a $ ^C
chymera@zenbookhost ~/data/cameras/nd750/a $ nd750_a0000.mkv  nd750_a0016.mkv  nd750_a0032.mkv  nd750_a0048.mkv  nd750_a0064.mkv  nd750_a0079.MOV
nd750_a0001.mkv  nd750_a0017.mkv  nd750_a0033.mkv  nd750_a0049.mkv  nd750_a0065.mkv  nd750_a0080.mkv
nd750_a0002.mkv  nd750_a0018.mkv  nd750_a0034.mkv  nd750_a0050.mkv  nd750_a0066.mkv  nd750_a0080.MOV
nd750_a0003.mkv  nd750_a0019.mkv  nd750_a0035.mkv  nd750_a0051.mkv  nd750_a0067.mkv  nd750_a0081.mkv
nd750_a0004.mkv  nd750_a0020.mkv  nd750_a0036.mkv  nd750_a0052.mkv  nd750_a0068.mkv  nd750_a0081.MOV
nd750_a0005.mkv  nd750_a0021.mkv  nd750_a0037.mkv  nd750_a0053.mkv  nd750_a0069.mkv  nd750_a0082.mkv
nd750_a0006.mkv  nd750_a0022.mkv  nd750_a0038.mkv  nd750_a0054.mkv  nd750_a0070.mkv  nd750_a0082.MOV
nd750_a0007.mkv  nd750_a0023.mkv  nd750_a0039.mkv  nd750_a0055.mkv  nd750_a0071.mkv  nd750_a0083.mkv
nd750_a0008.mkv  nd750_a0024.mkv  nd750_a0040.mkv  nd750_a0056.mkv  nd750_a0072.mkv  nd750_a0083.MOV
nd750_a0009.mkv  nd750_a0025.mkv  nd750_a0041.mkv  nd750_a0057.mkv  nd750_a0073.mkv  nd750_a0084.mkv
nd750_a0010.mkv  nd750_a0026.mkv  nd750_a0042.mkv  nd750_a0058.mkv  nd750_a0074.mkv  nd750_a0084.MOV
nd750_a0011.mkv  nd750_a0027.mkv  nd750_a0043.mkv  nd750_a0059.mkv  nd750_a0075.mkv  nd750_a0085.mkv
nd750_a0012.mkv  nd750_a0028.mkv  nd750_a0044.mkv  nd750_a0060.mkv  nd750_a0076.mkv  nd750_a0085.MOV
nd750_a0013.mkv  nd750_a0029.mkv  nd750_a0045.mkv  nd750_a0061.mkv  nd750_a0077.mkv  nd750_a0086.mkv
nd750_a0014.mkv  nd750_a0030.mkv  nd750_a0046.mkv  nd750_a0062.mkv  nd750_a0078.mkv  nd750_a0086.MOV
nd750_a0015.mkv  nd750_a0031.mkv  nd750_a0047.mkv  nd750_a0063.mkv  nd750_a0079.mkv
```

As you can see, the `ls` is not printed, but its output is, though starting inline with the prompt...

I am wondering:

- What's going on here?
- How can I fix my terminal once this happens?
- How can I prevent my script from breaking the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not figured out what the issue was exactly (and am happy to accept an edit adding that info to this answer), but it seems I needed to kill the process for the script to return the user to a clean prompt. I did this by appending the following [to my function](https://github.com/TheChymera/repositorg/blob/master/repositorg/processing.py#L66):

```
while None in [p.poll() for p in processes]:
    time.sleep(0.5)
#We need to explicitly terminate the master process here, as otherwise the shell "hangs" and the user needs to press enter to return to a new prompt.
os.system('kill %d' % os.getpid())
```

Answer (score 0):

Some process may have turned `echo` off.  This can be checked using the `stty` command.  Typically this is what happens:

```
$ stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint ixoff -imaxbel iutf8
```

If it gets turned off:

```
$ stty -echo
```

Then hit enter 4 times, type `stty`:

```
$ $ $ $ $ speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint ixoff -imaxbel iutf8
-echo
```

To turn it back on, simply call `stty echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the keyboard interrupt and handle it cleanly.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt

Note, in a multiprocessed environment, you need to consider that the interrupt could occur anywhere (in the workers or parent thread) and you should kill all your workers before exiting the parent.

Comment: The issue was happening not when I interrupted the function, but after it finished executing.